# Trying to add a span into a <a> tag in a dynamic wordpress nav

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to add a span tag inside a tags on the sub  navigation on the second level on the page url below.

I have only been able to find solutions to do this to the main navigation  and children and grandchildren navigation.

How would this be possible with php of jquery?

http://satbulsara.com/luke-irwin/rugs/new-in/fishy/

Comment: What code are you using the return the navigation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this...

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/HgkLu/

```
$('.page-item-173 > ul > li > a').wrapInner('<span class="abc" />');
```

Comment: did something almost identical

Comment: $('.rugsNav a , .bottomRugsNav a').wrapInner("<span></span>");